# cant displaying JSON error - TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript, html, json

Im using basic html and javascript, and it doesnt work in any of my browsers or other computers. I get TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

It works when I use the dev tools/console though. I cannot find anything wrong with what im writing, so I tried a few different ways and all fail with the same error.

```html
<!doctyp html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Simple JSON</title>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            var info = { "Name":"My name", "Age":"My age", "links":{"PBS":"http://pbs.org", "Google":"http://google.com"}};
            
            var output = "";
            
            for (key in info.links){
                output += "<li><a href='"+info.links[key]+"'>"+key+"</a></li>";
            }
            document.getElementById('links').innerHTML = output;
        </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <ul id="links">
  
 </ul>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I swap the script above with this <script type="text/javascript">
            
            var person = '{"FirstName" : "Your Name","Food":"Chicken","links": { "PBS" : "http://pbs.org", "links" : "http://awebpage.com"} }';            
            
            var output = JSON.parse(person);
            person ="";
            for(key in output.links){
                      person += "<li><a href='"+output.links[key]+"'>"+key+"</a></li>";                
            }           
            document.getElementById('links').innerHTML = person;           
            
        </script>

Comment: Lol, thats all it was, and I thought the world was ending. Thanks guys. Been stuck on this for a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your javascript is in the head element and is executed before the actual elements in the body are ready. Put it in an event that is called when the content is ready

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var info = { "Name":"My name", "Age":"My age", "links":{"PBS":"http://pbs.org", "Google":"http://google.com"}};

    var output = "";

    for (key in info.links){
        output += "<li><a href='"+info.links[key]+"'>"+key+"</a></li>";
    }
    document.getElementById('links').innerHTML = output;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is running before the page has finished loading, so at the time of execution, your element with the ID `links` doesnt exist yet. Move the script to the bottom of the page and it should work fine.

```
<html>


<head>
    <title>Simple JSON</title>      
</head>
    <body>
        <ul id="links">

        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var info = { "Name":"My name", "Age":"My age", "links":{"PBS":"http://pbs.org", "Google":"http://google.com"}};

            var output = "";

            for (key in info.links){
                output += "<li><a href='"+info.links[key]+"'>"+key+"</a></li>";
            }
            document.getElementById('links').innerHTML = output;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `<script>` tag at the bottom of the body. The reason why you get null error is because at the time your javascript code executes `<ul>` tag has not been initialized yet.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is an interpreted language. You need to put your JavaScript code after the closure of the `<ul>` markup or more generally before `</body>`